# Dynamic Order by [variable] instead of column names?

Tags: abap, opensql

Is it possible to create a dynamic Order by? something like

```
Select * from ztable_name Order by variable_name
```

Or maybe are there any other way to do similar with this if it is not possible?
Thanks, Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide further detail to the answer of **vwegert**: In your example, `variable_name` has to be the name of a column (because you want to order by a column). But this goes not by using a text variable, but a text table. Imagine the table you want to order has 5 columns:

- COL1
- COL2
- COL3
- COL4
- COL5

If you want to order it dynamically by, let's say COL2 and COL4, it goes like this:

```
DATA: itab_order TYPE TABLE OF  char_72,
      wa_order   LIKE LINE OF   itab_order.

wa_order = 'COL2'.
APPEND wa_order TO itab_order.
wa_order = 'COL4'.
APPEND wa_order TO itab_order.

SELECT *
  FROM ztable_name
  INTO itab_ztable_name
  ORDER BY (itab_order).
  ENDSELECT.
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes. It did help. Thanks a lot for giving additional details in vwegert's answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/fc/eb3a53358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm?current_toc=%2Fen%2Fd3%2F2e974d35c511d1829f0000e829fbfe%2Fplain.htm&frameset=%2Fen%2Ffc%2Feb3990358411d1829f0000e829fbfe%2Fframeset.htm&node_id=472):

> **Specifying the Columns Dynamically**
>
> To specify the columns in the `ORDER BY` clause dynamically, use:
>   `SELECT ... ORDER BY (<itab>).` where `<itab>` is an internal table
>   with line type `C` and maximum length 72 characters containing the
>   column names.

Comment: appreciate the help, vwegert. I usually declare internal table like this, Data itab Type Table of ztable_name. 
I think i'm confused with how to do the itab with line type c and with the column names.

Comment: sorry. I did not saw the documentation before adding a Comment. Anyway. Thanks a lot for helping.